# Youtube Data Api V3 using React js showing results of previous fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, youtube-api, react-hooks

I was making a youtube clone in which user can search for a term and the youtube data API will show the desired results in react js but every time I am querying the data of the previous query is being shown.
When I am logging 'Post' ie the JSON data

**Searchquery Component*

```
    import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import Cards from './Cards'

    function SearchResults(props) {
        const query = props.match.params.query;
        const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
        useEffect(() => {
            axios({
                "method": "GET",
                "url": 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
                "params":{
                    'part':'snippet',
                    'maxResults':'20',
                    'key':'[API_KEY]',
                    'q':query
                }
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    setPosts(res.data.items)               
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
                console.log(posts); 
        },[query])

        return (
            <div>
                <Cards/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default SearchResults
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `console.log(posts)` step is happening earlier than `setPosts(res.data.items)` one.

To capture changes for `posts` I recommend to use `useEffect` hook as :

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(posts); 
}, [posts]);
```

Read further about `useEffect` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the `useEffect` hook you need to add `[query]` as a second parameter. It means that the callback function (first parameter of `useEffect` method) will not be executed until `query` variable is changed ==> I think you must change `[query]` by `[posts]`.

Just use this code :

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Cards from './Cards'

function SearchResults(props) {
    const query = props.match.params.query;
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            "method": "GET",
            "url": 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
            "params":{
                'part':'snippet',
                'maxResults':'20',
                'key':'[API_KEY]',
                'q':query
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {
                setPosts(res.data.items)               
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            console.log(posts); 
    },[posts])

    return (
        <div>
            <Cards/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchResults
```